# Array Added duplicate object

Tags: swift

Please Review my code below, When I add dictionary object to NSMutableArry, it gives me duplicate object.
**tempArray** is array where i want to save all objects.
**fields** is another array from where i will filter some objects.

```
let tempArray = NSMutableArray()
        for  i in 0..<fields.count {
            let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
            dict .setValue(fields[i].value(forKey: "interface_id"), forKey: "interface_id")
            dict .setValue(fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "type"), forKey: "type")
            dict .setValue(fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "icon"), forKey: "icon")

            if fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "type") == "Name"{
                dict .setValue("First Name", forKey: "label_name")
                dict .setValue("first_column", forKey: "column_name")
                tempArray.add(dict)

                dict .setValue("Last Name", forKey: "label_name")
                dict .setValue("last_column", forKey: "column_name")
                tempArray.add(dict)
            }
        }
```

**OutPut**

```
(
        {
        "interface_id" = 1;
        "type" = "Name";
        "icon" = "G.JPG";
        "label_name" = "Last Name";
        "column_name" = "last_column";

       },    
{
        "interface_id" = 2;
        "type" = "Name";
        "icon" = "G.JPG";
        "label_name" = "Last Name";
        "column_name" = "last_column";
       }
)
```

**But Expected Output :**

```
(
        {
         "interface_id"=1;
         "type"="Name";
         "icon"="G.JPG";
         "label_name"="First Name";
         "column_name"="first_column";
        },
  {
        "interface_id"=2;
        "type"="Name";
        "icon"="G.JPG",
        "label_name"="Last Name";
        "column_name"="last_column";
        }
  )
```

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NS[Mutable]Array` or `NS[Mutable]Dictionary`. Use a Swift array and a Swift dictionary.

Comment: If you do insist on using `NSMutableDictionary`, use `setObject(_:forKey:)`, not `setValue(_:forKey:)`. And use `object(forKey:)`, not `value(forKey:`).

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your code.
In same for loop iteration, you do this :

```
       if fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "type") == "Name"{
            dict .setValue("First Name", forKey: "label_name")
            dict .setValue("first_column", forKey: "column_name")
            tempArray.add(dict)

            dict .setValue("Last Name", forKey: "label_name")
            dict .setValue("last_column", forKey: "column_name")
            tempArray.add(dict)
        }
```

which will first set the label_name to First Name and then correct it to Last Name.

Because you don't change anything in regarding the loop iteration, there should be no difference between each loop.

### EDIT:

Thanks to comment from @rmaddy. 
I totally agree: Do not use NSMutableDictionary inside Swift, unless you really know why you need it. (Objects referencing,... - NSMutableDictionary and Dictionary from Swift has different memory management rules).

Also I would avoid using .setValue or .setObject for that matter. I would rather use

```
dict["column_name"] = "last_column"
```

I think it is more clear.

***Steps of your code (explained):***

1. First you create array

so:

```
let tempArray = NSMutableArray()  // ---> tempArray = []
```

2. You go trough first loop of iteration (i == 0 )
3. You create dictinary

so:

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary() // ----> dict  = {}
```

4. You add three values inside

so:

```
dict .setValue(fields[i].value(forKey: "interface_id"), forKey: "interface_id")
dict .setValue(fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "type"), forKey: "type")
dict .setValue(fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "icon"), forKey: "icon")
//   ----->  dict = {"interface_id" : 1, "type" : "Name", "icon" : "G.JPG"}
```

5. Then you check if "type" == "Name"
6. Because it is true you add

so:

```
dict .setValue("First Name", forKey: "label_name")
dict .setValue("first_column", forKey: "column_name")
//   ----->  dict = {"interface_id" : 1, "type" : "Name", "icon" : "G.JPG", "label_name": "First Name", "column_name": "first_column"}
```

7. you add this dictionary to array

so:

```
// ----->  tempArray = [dict] // Notice that I put here only pointer to the dict
```

8. you change dictionary to

so:

```
//   ----->  dict = {"interface_id" : 1, "type" : "Name", "icon" : "G.JPG", "label_name": "Last Name", "column_name": "last_column"}
```

In this moment, you change object witch dict is pointing at: so this mean that inside tempArray now you have this new values in first position :

```
// it is still 
// ----->  tempArray = [dict]
// but : dict = {"interface_id" : 1, "type" : "Name", "icon" : "G.JPG", "label_name": "Last Name", "column_name": "last_column"}
```

**That is the reason why don't use NSMutableDictinary and NSMutableArray in Swift if you absolutely don't know why you are using them**

The suggested code would be:

```
var tempArray: [Any] = []
    for  i in 0..<fields.count {
        let dict:[String:String] = [:]
        dict["interface_id"] = fields[i].value(forKey: "interface_id")
        dict["type"] = fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "type")
        dict["icon"] = fields.fields[i].value(forKey: "icon")

        if dict["type"] == "Name"{
            dict["label_name"] = "First Name"
            dict["column_name"] = "first_column"
            tempArray.append(dict)


            // In Swift Array we append object not reference, so this is working now.
            dict["label_name"] = "Last Name"
            dict["column_name"] = "last_column"
            tempArray.add(dict)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then how i will do ?

Comment: Could you pleas provide me some logic, why you expect second column to be different then first,...

Comment: Use `setObject(_:forKey:)`, not `setValue(_:forKey:)`. And use `object(forKey:)`, not `value(forKey:)`. In other words, do not needlessly use key-value coding unless you have a clearly understood reason to do so. Better yet, don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: @InderpalSingh, Check my edit... I think I understand what you ware trying to do....